# Slick's carousel space between images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### Explanation

I'm using Ken Wheeler's plugin, [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), in order to create this carousel, but for some reason, the images inside `<a>` tag doesn't have a equal distance between themselves; some of them are even overlapping. Is there anything that solves it?

### Code

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #419be0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='carousel'>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance, 
Luiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your images are shown on their original size, which can be bigger than the size of the slides.

Making the `a` and `img` fit the slides gets rid of the overlap. You can of course tweak this to have some space between the slides, center the images vertically, et cetera.

**Original, but make all images fill slides**

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #419be0;
}

/* new */
a, img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='carousel'>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Original, but make all images fill slides and insert space**

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #419be0;
}

/* new */
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='carousel'>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Original, but use CSS `background-image` and margin**
This makes images fill the available space and inserts space between the images.

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #419be0;
}

/* new */
.container .slick-slide {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='container'>
  <div class='carousel'>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

**Original, but use CSS `background-image` (`contain`) and margin**
This makes images fit in the available space and inserts space between the images.

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #419be0;
}

/* new */
.container .slick-slide {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='container'>
  <div class='carousel'>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!! But how do I add this space between the images?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a couple of variations. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.carousel').slick({
    variableWidth: true,
    ...
});
```

variableWidth allows to use slides with different width.

To add space between slides via css you can use this:

```
.slick-slide {margin-right: 20px;}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It solved this problem, but it isn't responsive anymore. I mean `slidesToShow` doesn't work. It's showing as many slides as the width of the browser lets.